# Error Parsing in python

Tags: python, parsing

```
import urllib
import json


url = "http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opfileinc=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=4"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())

for f in data:
    a = json.loads(f)[u'update_date'][u'summary']
```

I have a error :

```
line 13, in <module>
    a = json.loads(f)[u'update_date'][u'summary']
```

I want the summary of that json just for example because if i just print the f var in the for cycle everything is ok.

```
{u'update_date': u'2013-11-25', u'cve_id': u'CVE-2013-6868', u'exploit_count': u'0', u'summary': u'SAP Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) 15.0.3 before 15.0.3 ESD#4.3, 15.5 before 15.5 ESD#5.3, and 15.7 before 15.7 SP50 or 15.7 SP100 allows local users to obtain sensitive information via unspecified vectors.', u'url': u'http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-6868/', u'publish_date': u'2013-11-23', u'cvss_score': u'7.8', u'cwe_id': u'200'}
{u'update_date': u'2013-11-25', u'cve_id': u'CVE-2013-6867', u'exploit_count': u'0', u'summary': u'Unspecified vulnerability in SAP Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) 15.7 before 15.7 SP50 or 15.7 SP100 allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service via unspecified vectors.', u'url': u'http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-6867/', u'publish_date': u'2013-11-23', u'cvss_score': u'7.1', u'cwe_id': u'0'}
{u'update_date': u'2013-11-27', u'cve_id': u'CVE-2013-6866', u'exploit_count': u'0', u'summary': u'SAP Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE) before 15.0.3 ESD#4.3, 15.5 before 15.5 ESD#5.3, and 15.7 before 15.7 SP50 or 15.7 SP100 allows remote authenticated users to execute arbitrary code via unspecified vectors, aka CR736689.', u'url': u'http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-6866/', u'publish_date': u'2013-11-23', u'cvss_score': u'9.0', u'cwe_id': u'94'}
```

I feel its a basic error but i'm not seeing the flaw.

Well after some search i got the expected result but thanks for all the fast help heres the final code:

```
#cvedetails_parser.py
import urllib
import son


url = "http://www.cvedetails.com/json-feed.php?numrows=10&vendor_id=0&product_id=0&version_id=0&hasexp=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opfileinc=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opginf=0&opdos=0&orderby=3&cvssscoremin=4"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)

data = json.loads(response.read())

for f in data:
    print "Update Date:", f['update_date']
    print "CVE ID:", f['cve_id']
    print "Number of Exploits:", f['exploit_count']
    print "CVSS Score:", f['cvss_score']
    print "Publish Date: ", f['publish_date']
    print "Summary: ", f['summary']
    print "\n"
    print "--------------------------------"
    print "--------------------------------"
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get as the value of `a`?

Comment: i see the error is :
print "Summary: ", f['summary'] 

and everything is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to call loads twice, after first call 'data' and hence its entries 'f' are also of type dict

```
for f in data:
    print f['update_date']
    print f['summary']
```